# Получение имени метода и класса для вывода в отладочный лог

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как можно получить имя текущего (исполняющегося) метода, для последующего вывода этой информации в отладочный лог, или, может быть, существует готовое решение?

Comment: в java интересует?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте макрос

```
__FUNCTION__
```

но это решение не очень переносимо.